# Showing that a piecewise function is analytic on a domain that includes the real-axis and is symmetric about the x-axis

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

I have the following problem:

"Suppose f is an analytic function on a domain D that includes the real-axis and which is symmetric about the real-axis. Suppose also that when $x$ is real, $f(x)$ is purely imaginary. Then $f(\overline{z})=-\overline{f(z)}$."

My idea so far has been to define the piecewise function $g:D\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be:

$g(z)=f(z)$ if $z\in D^+\cup D\cap \mathbb{R}$ and $g(z)=-\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ if $z\in D^{-}$,

where $D^+=${$z\in D | Im(z)>0$} and $D^-=${$z\in D | Im(z)<0$}.

Where I'm stuck now is showing that the function $g$ is holomorphic on D. I would like to show $g$ is holomorphic on D because then, by the Identity Theorem, $f=g$ on all of $D$ and I get the result I want. Does anyone have any hints on how to begin showing that $g$ is holomorphic on D?

Comment: why not just define $h(z)=\overline{f(\overline{z})}+f(z)$ and show that is well defined, analytic and zero on the real part of $D$, so it is zero everywhere etc

Comment: Oh I hadn’t thought about it like that, that seems much more straightforward than my approach. I’ll give your suggestion a try, thank you so much!